# Access global map variable inside active choice reactive reference parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to set a global map variable in a jenkins declarative pipeline. I am trying to access it inside an Active Choice Reactive Reference parameter. I tried many ways to achieve this but nothing worked.

Below is my sample Pipeline.

```
def sampleMap= [
    'students' : ['12312312'],
    'teachers' : ['145436436']
]


pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('set params') {
        steps{
           script {
                properties([
                    parameters([
                         [
                            $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
                            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
                            description: '', 
                            filterLength: 1, 
                            filterable: false, 
                            name: 'Type', 
                            randomName: 'choice-parameter-1325654724334254', 
                            referencedParameters: '', 
                            script: [
                                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                fallbackScript: [
                                    classpath: [], 
                                    sandbox: true, 
                                    script: ''
                                ], script: [
                                    classpath: [], 
                                    sandbox: true, 
                                    script: '''
                                        def choices = []
                                        choices.add('students')
                                        choices.add('teachers')
                                        return choices'''
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            $class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
                            choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML',
                            description: '',
                            name: 'value',
                            randomName: 'choice-parameter-14347325234254',
                            referencedParameters: 'Type',
                            script: [
                                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                                fallbackScript: [
                                        classpath: [],
                                        sandbox: true,
                                        script: ""
                                        ],
                                script: [
                                    classpath: [],
                                    sandbox: true,
                                    script: '''
                                        def result= ${sampleMap.get(Type)}
                                        return """<input name=\"value\" value=\"${result}\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">""" 
                                        '''
                                ]
                            ],
                            omitValueField: true
                        ]
                    ])
                ])
           }
        }
    }
}
```

As per above script, I have a global Map variable with list of students and list of teachers. I have two build parameters named as Type and value. Type is a dropdown with values 'students' and 'teachers' . Based on the dropdown selection, I want to refer to the global map variable and access it's respective value in another build parameter.

It seems like the active choice parameter is unable to access global variables. Or is that a syntax issue?

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: try `parameters: ['sampleMap': sampleMap]`

Comment: @daggett: came across your suggested solution and tried it - no matter what, i keep getting ```WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript': parameters```
Where/how does one set this parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass whole map into script and call it:

```
[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
    choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
    filterLength: 1,
    filterable: false,
    name: 'value',
    referencedParameters: 'Type',
    script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
        fallbackScript: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: true,
            script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
        ],
        script: [
            classpath: [],
            sandbox: true,
            script: """
                def sampleMap = ${sampleMap.inspect()}
                return sampleMap.get(Type)
                """.stripIndent()
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Has anybody tested this solution? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: yeah doesnt work.  also tried the parameters arg, that seems to not work either