# Accessing global variables from an Active Choice parameter's script block in a declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have the following code in my Jenkinsfile:

```
def testList = ['a','b','c']

properties([[
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        description: 'Some description',
        filterLength: 1, 
        filterable: true, 
        name: 'TestParameter',
        randomName: 'choice-parameter-47114921421532360', 
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 'return [\'ERROR\']'
            ],
            script: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 'return testList'
            ]
        ]]
]])
```

How can I get the value of testList to the script block here **without string interpolation**?

I do not want to use string interpolation because in production, testList will be dynamically populated. This has the nasty side effect of having to reapprove the script block in Jenkins via Script Approval every time testList is modified. I also do not want to expose an additional parameter to the user here (I could use a Choice parameter to get testList and then use "param.myChoiceParameter" to get the Active Choice working). And finally, I don't know if it would solve my issue, but I don't want the effort of creating a shared library at this time.

Things I've tried and either didn't work or had side effects.

- String interpolation with inspect ("return $testList.Inspect()}" in the script block)
- Adding @field to testList
- [Some other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67664780/access-global-map-variable-inside-active-choice-reactive-reference-parameter) said to add an ArrayList object to Parameters, which throws an an exception saying an ArrayList type is not recognized as a parameter type.

Comment: Why not literally assign the value to the map key via `script: testlist`?

Comment: Couldn't tell which script block you are referring to, so I tried both. I get this error message: 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [[testList, [a, b, c]]

Comment: To be honest: there are no script blocks in your provided code, so I had to guess what you are trying to do. Based on the error though, it sounds like you cannot provide dynamic properties like this. have you considered using a `parameters` directive instead?

Comment: A little confused. There are two mappings called "script" in the code provided.

Unfortunately, parameters directive will not work because I am trying to use Active Choices.